# Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for UR

Tags: java, url, base64, soapui

Tengo este metodo:

```
private static String descargaBase64(String urlStr) throws IOException {
        String pdf64 = "";
        try{
             URL url = new URL(urlStr);
                HttpURLConnection uc = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                uc.setRequestProperty ("iv-user", "51181873");
                uc.addRequestProperty("User-Agent", 
                        "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)");
                BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(uc.getInputStream());
                File temp = File.createTempFile("tempfile", ".pdf");
                FileOutputStream fis = new FileOutputStream(temp);
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                int count=0;
                while((count = bis.read(buffer,0,1024)) != -1)
                {           
                    fis.write(buffer, 0, count);
                }
                fis.close();
                bis.close();
               
                FileInputStream fs = new FileInputStream(temp);
                byte byteArray[] = new byte[(int)temp.length()];
                fs.read(byteArray);
                pdf64 = Base64.encode(byteArray);
                fs.close();
                temp.delete();
        }catch(IOException e){
            System.out.println("IOException. Fallo a la hora de crear el documento en Base64, motivo: " + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Exception. Fallo a la hora de crear el documento en Base64, motivo: " + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
       
        return pdf64;
    }
```

Me esta dando un problema en la linea **BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(uc.getInputStream());** :

> IOException. Fallo a la hora de crear el documento en Base64, motivo:
> Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL:

Y me gustaría saber qué es ya que añadí (mirando en otros foros) la linea

```
uc.addRequestProperty("User-Agent", 
                        "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)");
```

Pero me sigue fallando. ¿Alguna sugerencia?

Cualquier duda o aclaración decidmelo y lo reviso

Muchas gracias anticipadas y un saludo.

Comment: 403 es forbidden, el por qué de ese código http dependerá de la API que estés atacando, normalmente se devuelven cuando has intentado acceder algo a lo que no deberías haber accedido. Tal vez te falte enviar algún tipo de autenticación en la petición? Realmente es imposible ayudarte sin saber qué espera recibir el servidor, sinceramente. Podrías al menos indicar la API que estás intentando consumir para ver si hay algún tipo de documentación... pero ya puestos, podrías *buscar la **documentación** de dicha API* y ver ***qué espera recibir***

Comment: Voy a consumir un Servicio SOAP. No sé si te refieres a esto. Un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que te esta diciendo es que te faltan credenciales para poder consumir el servicio que estas solicitando, por ejemplo si fuese una autenticacion basica seria de acuerdo a este [hilo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12732422/adding-header-for-httpurlconnection)

```
String userCredentials = "usuario:password";
String basicAuth = "Basic " + new 
String(Base64.getEncoder().encode(userCredentials.getBytes()));
myURLConnection.setRequestProperty ("Authorization", basicAuth);
```

Este ejemplo puede que no sea funcional para ti, pero la idea es que necesitas proveer credenciales al servicio para que te de la autorizacion de consumirlo. El Http error 403 significa que no tienes el permiso para consumir dicho servicio, dependiendo de que manera se autentifique un usuario puede variar el header que se necesita o como mandes las credenciales para consumir el servicio.

Comment: Gracias, es posible que sea por las credencias. Estoy hablando con la persona responsable del servicio que se va a consumir. A ver qué me cuenta.